# Does the Corda network become fault tolerant and available as it uses RAFT consensus algorithm?

Tags: corda, raft

Does the Corda network become fault tolerant and available as it uses RAFT consensus algorithm?

As I understand the consensus algorithm is used for the consensus part where nodes agree on something. This does not necessarily mean that the entire Corda network is fault tolerant and available. It also depends on all the network components (clustered node or individual node, cordapp, Corda network services etc..)

Answer (score 1):

RAFT consensus algorithm has been introduced as experimental feature for a fault-tolerant Notary service cluster only. It cannot be applied to Corda nodes, at least not until the current version (4.x).

From the documentation:

> Corda provides a prototype Raft-based highly available notary implementation. You can try it out on our notary demo page. Note that it has known limitations and is not recommended for production use.

You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/running-a-notary.html#crash-fault-tolerant-experimental) and the sample on github [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/release/os/4.8/samples/notary-demo).